# missing System.Windows reference

Tags: silverlight, reference, namespaces

I have a Silverlight application where I need to use the Vector class in System.Windows within the Web project.  But VS is complaining that System.Windows does not exist.  I tried adding the reference, but it's not in the list of namespaces to add.  In the .NET tab, it goes from System.Web.Services to System.Windows.Forms and skips System.Windows altogether.

What's really strange is that System.Windows DOES exist int the reference list in the Silverlight project.  Furthermore, I have another Silverlight app on this machine with exactly the same setup (two projects, one Silverlight, one Web), and the reference is there.

I saw someone else here had a similar problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it!  You have to add a reference to WindowsBase.

The usual way (I guess) to set up a Silverlight app is to have two projects: one for the Silverlight client code, and one for the server side aspx pages.  The Silverlight reference pool has System.Windows available in it.  The aspx reference pool does not.  What it has instead, is the "WindowsBase" dll, which makes the System.Windows namespace (and probably others) available in your "using" block.  But it's not included in the project by default.

Comment: This didnt work for me. I am trying to use System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage, so i guess that is not in WindowsBase.  (Note: I can add a reference to System.Windows.DLL on the (sliverlight) client side, but not on the Server side.

Comment: it is in 
(#region Assembly System.Windows.dll, v2.0.50727
// c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Windows.dll
#endregion)
So only available on the Silverlight Client side. I will look at using System.Drawing.Image instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the solution posted by Klay does not work with Silverlight 5 (at least not on my machine).

**Alternatively you can use
*Vector2* class from *Microsoft.Xna.Framework***

But this requires a little rewriting of code based on System.Windows.Vector, since the VNA Vector2 uses floats instead of doubles.